# Keep scientific notation in output file's name using ostringstream, etc

Tags: c++, input, output

I am practicing input-output, I read two vectors from files f1 and f2, they are shown in the figure.
[image]

I want to use the content of two files for the output file's name. So the code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> f1Series;
    vector<double> f2Series;
    double tmp;

    std::ifstream input;
    input.open("Input/f1.txt");
    while (input >> tmp) f1Series.push_back(tmp);
    input.close();

    input.open("Input/f2.txt");
    while (input >> tmp) f2Series.push_back(tmp);
    input.close();



    std::ostringstream oss1;
    std::ostringstream oss2;
    oss1 <<  f1Series[1];
    oss2 <<  f2Series[1];
    std::string f1 = oss1.str();
    std::string f2 = oss2.str();


    std::ofstream st("Output/Results" + f1 + "_" + f2 + ".txt");

}
```

However, the current result is

```
Results1e07_0.001000.txt
```

What I want is

```
Results1e7_1e-3.txt
```

Comment: FYI: [std::scientific](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5de5bc8c0a9a66e)

Comment: Use `std::getline` to read the lines as `std::string` and use that when creating the filename? You can convert the read line into a `double` too (using `std::stod` for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try [std::scientific](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

```
double c = 1.0e-10;
std::cout << std::scientific; //setting output format
std::cout << c;
```

The output will be

```
1.00000e-010
```

Comment: OP wants `Results1e7_1e-3.txt`. I'm not sure this answer explains how to get to that.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the lines you read as strings, not converted to `double`.  You'll need to later convert to `double` when you are ready to use it as a number, but you are remembering the characters you actually scanned so you can reproduce that in the file name.

```
vector<string> f1Series;
vector<string> f2Series;
```

Comment: How to reproduce it?

Comment: Read and remember **the string**.  "reproduce" means when you use that string (not a number converted to string) in the filename, it will be exactly what you read.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` way, easy to remember if you are used to C, but definitely C-ish and old fashioned:

```
char temp[16];
snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "Results%.0e.txt", f1Series[1]);
std::ostream st(temp);
```

The C++ way using `scientific` and `setprecision`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Results" <<std::scientific << std::setprecision(0) << f1Series[1] << ".txt";
std::string filename = oss.str();
```